# export all properties from object as non default

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been wanting to do this, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
const settings = {
  PENDING_ACTION_TIME: 100000
}

export default settings
export {...settings}
```

This way I can do

```
import {PENDING_ACTION_TIME} from '../settings'
```

or

```
import settings from '../settings'
```

I know I could export each properties one by one by that seems like stupid code repetition if you have something like 20 properties.

Answer (score 1):

Don't start with an object in the first place. Use named exports instead:

```
const PENDING_ACTION_TIME = 100000;
```

This way you can do

```
import {PENDING_ACTION_TIME} from '../settings';
```

or a [namespace import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_an_entire_modules_contents)

```
import * as settings from '../settings';
```

You could also use the namespace object in a default export, but you really shouldn't.

Comment: what's a namespace object? your solution doesn't really fix the problem, sure it gives name exports without code repetition, but it removes the default export. my goal is to keep both while avoiding code repetition

Comment: @user12341234 My answer is that you don't need a default-exported object when you can do `import * as settings` which achieves the same goal with named exports.

Comment: @user12341234 what you are asking for isn't supported as far as I'm aware, this is by far the closest in terms of syntax and would be the equivalent in terms of accomplishing tree shaking when importing specific properties. Get the idea of the default export out your head, it makes no difference

Comment: @James I disagree, import * looks ugly and most modules choose not to use it, they have a default export and named exports at the same time, because it looks nice

Comment: @user12341234 No. They don't do this because it looks nice (namespace imports are far superior), but because of backwards-compatibility with commonjs and the weird things transpilers in the past. Notice that all the libraries that do this have the duplication in their export code.

Comment: @Bergi I made few corrections to my answer. Could that be mixed with ES6 style modules to achieve the required behaviour? Like by creating an intermediate file just for imports and exports?

Comment: @AkshitMehra It might work (depending on the used environment and transpiler, so I'm not sure), but I wouldn't recommend it - the best practice is ES6 modules throughout.